# Как сделать что бы автоматически открывалась дочерна страница

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Можете подсказать как сделать что бы при открытии родительской страницы открывалась одна из дочерных одновременно. Вот блок где меню с дочерными страницами. Страница интегрирована на WP. Нужно как на картинке

```
<?php if ( in_array (get_the_ID(), array(34, 40 , 61, 42, 44, 46) ) ) { ?>
<!-- Navigation About-->    
<section class="navigation navigation_about" id="navigation navigation_about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h1 class="navigation__title">
                     О компании
                </h1>
                <?php $title = the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>', false ); ?>
                <?php if (function_exists('dimox_navigation__main')) dimox_navigation__main(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-lg-2 col-lg-6">
                <div class="divide">
                    <nav>
                       <?php
                            if($post->post_parent)
                              $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
                            else
                              $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
                            if ($children) { ?>
                            <ul class="divide__list">
                              <?php echo $children; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Что значит "отркывалась одна из дочерних страниц одновременно"? Какая должна открываться? Как? Где?

Comment: При открытии родительской страницы где находятся меню дочерных страниц, хочу что бы одна из них загружалась сразу на родительской. Сейчас у меня просто блок с меню этих страниц которые открываются по клику

Comment: ?? Что мешает поставить ссылку не на родительскую, а на дочернюю?